# Un-wordwrapping columns in MS Project 2013

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to "un-wordwrap" columns in MS Project 2013. According to the docs, if I toggle wordwrap off and then manually adjust each row, wordwrap will snap off. I was hoping for something more Excel like where I can switch back and forth--sometimes I need to read my "Notes" column, say; other times my focus is on project dependencies and seeing all of the elements in a WBS section.

Any way to get to the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unwordwrap en masse I've used the following process:

1. Select the column to unwordwrap
2. Select the rows involved (sometimes all)
3. On any selected row move your cursor until it becomes the row high adjustment icon, then drag upward.

This should shrink all rows back to no wrap.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it. But it still looks like an awkward activity when you have a slew of rows to be selected.